# Approximation of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

When we take the Fourier transform of $\cos({2 \pi f_0 x})$ on a finite interval $[-a, a]$, even though we increase the $a$ too much, there is still contributions from other frequencies rather than $f_0$. Why don't the contributions other frequencies in the Fourier transform graph become zero as we increase the integral range?

$$
\int_{-a}^{a}{\cos\left(2{\pi}f_0x\right)\cdot\mathrm{e}^{-2\mathrm{i}{\pi}fx}} = \dfrac{\left(f_0-f\right)\sin\left(2{\pi}af_0+2{\pi}af\right)+\left(f_0+f\right)\sin\left(2{\pi}af_0-2{\pi}af\right)}{2{\pi}\cdot\left(f_0^2-f^2\right)}
$$

For $f_0 = 3$;

$$
\dfrac{\left(f-3\right)\sin\left(2{\pi}af+6{\pi}a\right)+\left(f+3\right)\sin\left(2{\pi}af-6{\pi}a\right)}{2{\pi}\cdot\left(f^2-9\right)}
$$
When we take the integral over the $[-4,4]$, the Fourier transform looks as following.

[image: Graph 1]

over the $[-8,8]$,

[image]

over the $[-40,40]$

[image]

Why don't the contributions from other frequencies become close to zero as we increase the range to $[-\infty, \infty]$? How does one explain this?

Comment: Why should they? You might get better behaviour if you look at the same thing but normalised by $1/a$ or $1/2a$ whatever, as is usual in computing the Fourier coefficienfs

Comment: I know the exact Fourier transform over $[-\infty, \infty]$ is $\frac{\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)}{2}$, so I would expect it to converge to this expression.

Comment: When you take the Fourier integral from $-a$ to $a$, it is the same as taking the Fourier integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ of the argument times the "top hat" function which is $1$ on $[-a,a]$ and $0$ otherwise. The Fourier transform of this top hat function is a [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). Note that the limit of a sinc function is indeed one of the representations of the delta function.

Comment: @JohnBarber Oh, thank you so much! I am new to Fourier Transform and wasn't aware of $sinc$ function. It really makes sense now.